# Best method for Image scaling to fullscreen, depending on viewport size

Tags: jquery, css, image, xhtml

I am working on a little site, providing high quality photography by three photographers.
By now, when you click on a image, it scales to fit the wrapper, which actually means 1000px width. The ratio is 4:3.

**Further I am now cloning the image and appending it to the body and scaling it up to viewport size by setting `height` to `100%`.**

**Can I do it any other way and consider, that it is cross-platform compatible? please give me some Feedback**

A live example of actual Site: [NicRay](http://www.nicray.com)

Comment: its x-browser down to IE7 and i guess fast enough, why want to change it? btw. your Logo font is cut in IE7

Comment: The large photos you see have an resolution of 1000px to 800px. I want them to be shown in high quality even for a Full HD resolution(1920 x 1080)! Thanks for the advice!

Comment: i cant follow you... you use 100% height but want it to be shwon as "HD" 1080 height. nevermind i post an answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create something like an overlay... what you already use. fill this overlay with the whole screen (100% x 100% and position fixed) and use a table inside where you center the content vert. and hori...

now begin to measure your clicked image and the users screen height and width and append the image depending if image is to high or too broad for the screen:

```
$('img').click(function(){

 var image_w = $(this).width();
 var image_h = $(this).height();
 var screen_w = $('.overlay').width();
 var screen_h = $('.overlay').height();
 if (image_w > screen_w) var w = true;

 if (w) {
  $('.overlay table tr td').append('<img src="'+$(this).attr('src')+'" width="'+screen_w+'" />');
  //showOverlay() function..
  return false;
 } else {
  $('.overlay table tr td').append('<img src="'+$(this).attr('src')+'" height="'+screen_h+'" />');
  //showOverlay() function..
  return false;
 }

});
```

untested but should work on the fly... but remember this works only width really big image sizes. if your images "only" have about 1500 pixel height implement a condition and set a max size for the image, otherwise its overdimensioned and ugly.

Comment: i already solved my problem by my own but your answer is very very very nice! +1